# Download via FTP com JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, java, ftp

Gostaria de saber como posso estar colocando em minha página a opção do usuário fazer o download via FTP. Não quero que o usuário digite as informações para acesso ao FTP e também que ele não veja os dados do FTP que está acessando para fazer o download.

Isso é possível? Se sim como posso proceder ?

Comment: Coloca um LINK assim: www.dominio.com.br/pasta/arquivo.rar

Comment: Diego obrigado pela atenção mais deste modo não funcionou

Comment: Sem ter como ele ver os dados é impossível, não tem como acessar o FTP sem o endereço, e caso ele necessite de usuário e senha estes vão ter que estar em algum lugar que por mais que você tente esconder vão ter que ser usados pelo navegador para baixar o arquivo, logo podem ser descobertos.

Answer (score 1):

Até é possível fazer, mas nos browsers mais atuais você recebe uma tela de confirmação informando que pode ser uma possível fraude.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o trecho:

```
var username = 'user';
var password = 'pass';
var server = 'toSomeServer';
window.open("ftp://" + username + ":" + 
      password + "@" + server, '_blank', 
      'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,' + 
      'scrollbars=auto,copyhistory=no,menubar=no,width=' 
      + ((screen.AvailWidth/2)-12) + ',height=' 
      + (screen.AvailHeight-124) +',left=' + ((screen.AvailWidth/2)) 
      + '),top=0,resizable=yes');
```

Creio que não seja a solução mais elegante para isso.

Uma **boa alternativa** seria você tratar isso no serverside.
No site da [Wc3](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_ftp_connect.asp) tem um exemplo de conexão com PHP.

Espero ter ajudado.